# Arduino Wifi ESP8266 error

Tags: arduino

i am trying to connect an **arduino** uno using **esp2866** to my home router and i am getting th is error

> C:\Users\john-\Documents\Arduino\newww\newww.ino:2:25: fatal error:
>   ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory   #include 
>   ^  compilation terminated.  exit status 1 Error compiling for board
>   Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

ESP8266WiFi.h is [part](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src) of the [ESP8266 core for Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/). That core is used to add support to the Arduino IDE for directly programming the ESP8266. The file ESP8266WiFi.h is only accessible when you have one of the ESP8266 core for Arduino's boards selected from the **Tools > Board** menu. However, you are not directly programming the ESP8266 and do not have one of the ESP8266 core for Arduino's boards selected. You are programming the Uno and thus you will not be able to use ESP8266WiFi.h.

Comment: what should i do to allow the arduino connect to the router i bought an arduino uno and an esp2866 and my aim is to send data from the arduino to a php server using wifi

Answer (score -1):

You need to use serial AT firmware on ESP8266 and connect the ESP8266 to UNO with two Rx and Tx pins. After that you will be able to send correct AT commands to open socket and communicate thru the Internet.

You can install AT firmware from [here](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266_AT-Command_firmware).

In the example given below, GPIOs on UNO 2 and 3 will be connected on the RX and TX of the ESP8266. Do not forget to cross connect the RX and TX on each other.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial wifiSerial(2, 3);      // RX, TX for ESP8266

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(baud); // Serial for UNO output
  wifiSerial.begin(9600); // Serial for ESP8266 AT input
}

void loop() 
{
    while(wifiSerial.available() > 0) 
    {
      char a = wifiSerial.read();
      if(a == '\0')
        continue;
      if(a != '\r' && a != '\n' && (a < 32))
        continue;
      Serial.print(a);
    }

    while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char a = Serial.read();
      Serial.write(a);
      wifiSerial.write(a);
    }
}
```

With this example, your SerialMonitor will be able to receive AT commands. You can write the AT command to connect to the Wi-Fi. Check some basic commands from [here](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266_AT-Command_firmware).

After you tested the commands and OK, you will put these commands into specific functions. i.e.:

```
void connectToWiFi()
{
  //super simply
  wifiSerial.write("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
  wifiSerial.write("AT+CWJAP=ssid,pass\r\n");
}
```

Comment: this answer doesn't address the problem in the question

Comment: ok the at command works fine but i need to send data, for example  collected by a sensor from arduino to a php server using internet or localy in my network, can this be done, i am new in this domain and your help is appreciated

Comment: Sure you can do, i will extend my answer by adding tcp socket operations.